# Instantiating a class within a recursive function in PHP

Tags: php, class, instantiation, redeclare

I've been creating a script using PHP and seem to have hit a brick wall at the moment with it. I'm trying to call a variable from another file which is within a class, so I went about it by including the file within the original and then instantiating the class to call the variable. But the entire thing is within a recursive function and I get Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class JVersion. I've pasted part of the code below:

```
... 
function functionname($path)
{
...
define('_JEXEC', true);
require_once ($path ."libraries/cms/version/version.php");
$test_class = new JVersion();
$jma_ver    = $test_class->getShortVersion();
...
functionname($path);
...
}
```

This is how the part of the code within the version.php looks like

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
final class JVersion
{
public $RELEASE = '2.5';
public $DEV_LEVEL = '1';
public function getShortVersion()
{
return $this->RELEASE.'.'.$this->DEV_LEVEL;
}
```

Is there a way I can overcome the "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class JVersion" error ?

Comment: Why are you doing this?  What is this meant to accomplish?  Why would you constantly define a constant over and over?  Why?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly (i.e. you have many classes named `JVersion` that you need to use), then I'm not sure of any way around this problem without namespacing your `JVersion` classes in some way. Either give them distinct names or put them in different PHP namespaces.

This sounds more like an architectural problem, really; the code you're using doesn't seem to provide a way of getting its version in a disposable manner (without setting yourself up for conflicts like this). Ideally, you should just have a global `JVersion` class that can be insantiated with the appropriate version numbers; this way there'd be no class name conflicts.

Comment: Oh, I don't have many classes named JVersion. It is only a single class, but since it is within a recursive function, it is being called multiple times.

Comment: Actually, I am calling the version number of the script by searching through the directories if a script is installed, and if it is, looking for the file and retrieving the version number from within the file, if you understand what I mean.

Comment: @Syed: You say there's only one class named `JVersion`, but you're including it with a different path on each invocation of `functionname`, so it's a different file each time. Even if they're all structurally identical, they're still different classes.